# Is deswegen a subordinating or coordinating conjunction?

Tags: conjunction

I've found on a number of websites they say deswegen is a subordinating conjunction wherease on some others they have said it is coordinating. I was wondering if someone could clarify this for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, Duden doesn't define it as a conjunction whatsoever. But as an adverb. DWDS, on the other hand, recognizes it as a conjunction.
So, apparently there's a debate on what this word really is.

[According to canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Klasse/Konjunktional.html?lang=en), it is a conjunctional adverb. So, it is an adverb that has the function of connecting to clauses. Exactly, what a conjunction also does. That's why some sources may recognize it as a conjunction.

Now, addressing your question: If you look at the word order, you will notice that sentences containing "deswegen" follow the word order of coordinating conjunctions — the finite verb is in the second position, that is.

That is, if you consider it being a conjunction, it's a coordinating conjunction. If you're on the side of those claiming it being an adverb, it's a conjunctional adverb.

Comment: I think it's less a debate of "what this word really is", and more a different usage of "conjunction": If you define "conjunction" as a word "between" sentences in a fixed position which joins sentences and marks subclauses ("und", "oder", "denn", "weil", "obwohl"), then it's an (conjunctional) adverb. If you define "conjunction" as anything that relates sentences, causally, temporally or otherwise, then it's a conjunction. However, it's distinct in word order from coordinating conjunctions like "und", "oder" etc. ("und er hat", "deswegen hat er").